# How to retrieve ethereum accounts?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

When i try to use ethAccounts() method of web3j it returns some object ..
so the question is how to get the output same as eth.accounts geth command ?

Comment: output : org.web3j.protocol.core.Request@d6da883

Comment: expected output : 0xd1821e427faf112401e7dd232dd16d305444a78a

Answer (score 1):

to get the accounts you have to use web3.eth.accounts.getAccounts() ( v1.0.x beta )

or web3.eth.accounts in lowest versions ( v0.20.x max )

Comment: thats working interms of web3 but i want to use web3j ... how about that ?

Comment: my bad, i thought the j of web3j was a typo. Can't help on this one as i don't do java :( 

Hope someone can help you

Comment: ;-p that's ok buddy